# Ajax jquery with facebook api

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to parse all the id's of the user likes with jquery. this is what i did but it doesnt work.

```
 $("#demo").live("click", function () {   

       var url="https://graph.facebook.com/facebookid/likes?access_token=XXXX?callback=?";

        $.getJSON(url, function(item){
         $.each(item.data, function(i,like) {
           var name = like.id;
           $("#dv").append(name);
           });
        });

    });
```

Comment: Why don't you use FB JS SDK?

Comment: @zerkms i just want to do it in this way and also wonder why this doesnt work.

Comment: if you're not confident enough to debug a trivial code - it's recommended to use libraries that just work.

Comment: if i was confident enough it would be easy for me to do it. but because i want to learn something new i use this website. i have seen plenty of examples which are done with this method and i want to know why this doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use simple AJAX ($.get, $.post, $.ajax) for request to another domains. You would read about JSONP... or about FB JA \S \

Comment: In JS you should use FB JS SDK (it sends JSONP-requests). JavaScript allows to send AJAX-request to your own domain only. Also you can send requests from server.